# Automatic logout codeigniter bonfire

Tags: codeigniter, bonfire

I create a web application in ci bonfire. I installed 2 bonfire. One for front end and another for backend. Installation sturcture is like:-

```
projectName  
Assets  
Bonfire  
Riadmin :- (It is another bonfire for admin panel)
Index.php
```

Now i am having a problem when i hit frontend "projectName" then the backend "Riadmin" is automatic logout and riadmin generate a log error like

```
ERROR - 2015-07-04 17:15:03 --> The session cookie data did not match what was expected. This could be a possible hacking attempt.
```

One this is to be notice that frontend is newly install but backend is copied fully from another project. The database is same for both.
How can i solve this problem.

Comment: Try changing the session cookie name in the application/config/config.php like $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'bf_session'; to $config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ra_session';                            Different session cookie for both of the installation.

Comment: Working :) @JubayerArefin

Comment: Lets make it the answer :) @gitesh-purbia

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the session cookie name in the application/config/config.php

like

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'bf_session';
```

to

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ra_session';
```

Different session cookie for both of the installation.